# Missing Fields When Adding Content

Tags: entities, nodes

When going to `node/add/my-content-type` there is only a field for editing the title. There are body and FileFields attached to this content type but they are not being displayed until *after* I click save.

The content type is an OG content type though I am not sure this has anything to do with the issue. I tried toggling `strict node access` but it didn't help.

Preview is disabled.

Comment: This is not a standard Drupal way of working. So you have some kind of bug or misconfiguration. Sadly, it's not possible for us to debug your site, and you have to admit that the amount of information you gave us is pretty low. And we don't know the context you do. Examine everything that interacts with your field permissions. Especially things that changed between the moment it was working OK and the moment it started working as it works now. Oh, and certainly see watchdog and error.log. And somewhere there should be your answer...

Comment: No problem. I suspect it is related to permissions as well since this is not occurring for the super user account. I've got some custom code that use _hook_node_access_ that I will double check that I just remembered about.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the **Organic Groups Field Access** module and the missing fields appeared.

Related to the OG issue: https://drupal.org/node/1743332

In summary, for some users, disabling/re-enabling this module while clearing the cache resolved the issue.